# Как подключить боту Telegram статистику?

Tags: php, api, telegram

Помогите пожалуйста подключить к PHP боту Telegram статистику его использования, с помощью Botan.io
Ничего не получается... :(

Сам бот создан по такой инструкции (там же исходники) - http://aftamat4ik.ru/bot-dlya-telegram-na-php-knopki-posting-inline-queryes/#reply-buttons

Comment: Нужно вместо "Ничего не получается... :(" в вопросе суть проблемы указать -- попытки включения сбора статистики

Comment: Я же привел ссылку, там полный код бота есть.

Comment: Я пробовал сразу после подключения API бота вот так $bot = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client($token,"TOKEN-BOTAN"); иногда бот просто перестает отвечать на другие команды, поэтому это не верный способ как я думаю...

Comment: А я не про бота спрашивал, а про сбор статистики. Хм, т.е. бот даже и не запущен вами?

Comment: Конечно бот запущен :) 100% по примеру из статьи (там исходник),  а статистика в телеграм только один вариант botan.io вот его я и не могу подключить :(